# Problems creating a Batch script to detect files and directories that have dots in their names

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, filenames

The problem I'm having is that my file names use dots, but no spaces.
My folder names use spaces, not dots.

For example, I have a file named:

```
C:\Files\One.Two.Three.Four.12.34.5.pdf
```

The corresponding folder is named:

```
C:\Files\One Two Three Four
```

I would like a script that would detect all of the `.pdf` files in the `C:\Files` directory, all of the folders in the `C:\Files` directory, and then figure out which folder the file should be placed into based on the naming structure given previously.

I'm having a problem with the dots being in the file name, but not in the folder name, as well as the fact that there's the extra `12.34.5` at the end of the file name that is not in the corresponding folder name. Also, the extra stuff after the One.Two.Three.Four tend to change randomly. It's not always `12.34.5`.

Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Clearly this can be done with some scripting. You’d respectfully be out of your mind doing this in a batch file. Use powershell at the very least. However, we’re not a script writing service. So you’ll have to figure out how to enumerate your folder names, convert the names to contain periods and search for files that start with that name and move them. Not an easy task for a novice, but not insurmountable for the diligent.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to happen:

```
file: "cat.dog.bird.tree.2345.pdf" to folder: "cat dog bird tree"
file: "egg.bacon.bread.coffee.efgh.pdf" to folder: "egg bacon bread coffee"
file: "mother.father.sister.brother.pdf" to folder: "mother father sister brother"
file: "one.two.three.four.5678.pdf" to folder: "one two three four"
```

...you can capture the first 4 tokens of the file name and put them back together with spaces instead of dots to form the folder name.

```
@echo off 
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /s /b *.pdf') do (
    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
        echo file: "%%A" to folder: "%%B %%C %%D %%E"
        )
    )
```

Note: this assumes that all .pdf files in the folder where the batch script is, and all subfolders, have this format: `token1.token2.token3.token4` followed by some characters (or no more characters), then the .pdf extension.